# How to convert a AFNetworking code to Alamofire?

Tags: ios, objective-c, alamofire, afnetworking

I want to convert the following code to Alamofire version, but I'm confused about the `AFHTTPSessionManager` part.

```
+(void)requestWithUrlString:(NSString *)URLstring method:(NSString *)method parameters:(NSMutableDictionary *)parameters success:(void (^)(id))success faiure:(void (^)(NSError *))failure{

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager sharedManager];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html",@"text/plain", nil ];

    manager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 20;

    [manager POST:URLstring parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        if (success) {
            success(responseObject);
        }
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        if (failure) {
            failure(error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Alamofire don't have  anything like  `AFHTTPSessionManager` it has direct method to send post request with required parameters  you can read this   https://www.raywenderlich.com/147086/alamofire-tutorial-getting-started-2

Comment: Yeah, I know it. But I'm not sure if it is right to include the entire `acceptableContentTypes`(MIME type) in the header and separate them with `,`.

Comment: You can use your required content-type , You don't need entire array of content type

Comment: But how to set the `timeout`? In the tutorial you sent to me, it seems that they were using Apple's `URLRequest` instead of `Alamofire`.

Comment: Please check My answer I have created helper class for same

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", method: .post, parameters: parameters as? [String : Any]).responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result
     {
case .success :                         
    case .failure :
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this class For Sending request

```
final class ServerManager: SessionManager {

    //----------------------------------------------------------------

   class var sessionConfig : URLSessionConfiguration {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 60 // seconds
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60
        return configuration

    }
    class var sessionConfigForDownload : URLSessionConfiguration {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20 // seconds
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 20
        return configuration

    }

    static let sharedManager = ServerManager(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: SessionDelegate.init(), serverTrustPolicyManager: nil)
    static let shareDownloadManager = ServerManager(configuration: sessionConfigForDownload, delegate: SessionDelegate.init(), serverTrustPolicyManager: nil)

    //------------------------------------------------------------

    override init(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration, delegate: SessionDelegate, serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager?) {
        super.init(configuration: configuration, delegate: delegate, serverTrustPolicyManager: serverTrustPolicyManager)
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------




    func postRequestToServer(_ url : String, parameter : Parameters? = nil, encoding : ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default, header : HTTPHeaders? = nil , success: @escaping (Any) -> Void, failure: @escaping (Error) -> Void) -> Void {
            self.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameter, encoding: encoding, headers: header).responseJSON{ (response) in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    print("Validation Successful")
                    success(response.result.value)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                    failure(error)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Note: This is just sample not tested using XCode. You can add your method like get, put , patch here same as in example i have shown

Hope  it is helpful to you